# override database with new Migrations asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

I created a new migration for my asp.net core Web API which applied the changes to my database, But I later deleted the migration manually. I now tried to add a new migration with new changes and but it is giving the error bellow since the changes from the migration I deleted were applied to the database already.

`An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: There is already an object named 'FK_TaskDates_Tasks_TaskId' in the database.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors`

Long story short, I'm trying to return the database state back to what it was before the deleted migration was applied.

Is there a way for me to revert the database back to it's working state?

Answer (score 1):

Migrations work by comparing the new migration to the last one run. If there are no prior migrations, it will script out everything in the database.

Generally, for existing database with no prior migrations, you will need to add baseline migration. With EF6 you can use the -IgnoreChanges flag for this baseline. EF Core does not have that (unless recently added), so you can work around it by commenting out the stuff already in the database in the `Up()` method and applying it. The important thing is that a copy of the model is captured for future comparisons.

Now the next migration you add will only include the changes from that model stored in the code file.

To get your current system working, just comment out the stuff that already exists in the `Up()` method and keep the changed stuff and apply it (`update-database`).